# Executing a batch script consecutively

Tags: python, shell

Hi I need to run sevral test cases while I am away from the machine. 
is there a possible way in user script to execute several commands one after another. 
the following commands should execute even if the commands before failed or threw out an error.

Example of the commands to run.

1) run.py -n test_app 2)run.py -n test_delete_app 3)run.py -n test_create_app

2 should execute after one even if 1 fails.

Comment: You can create a script that calls both of them consecutively.

Comment: run.py -n test_app; run.py -n test_delete_app; run.py -n test_create_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run several cmomands one after another independent of return values by separating them with `;`'s:

```
run.py -n test_app; run.py -n test_delete_app; run.py -n test_create_app
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked fine. I was able to do that using bash script as well.